# Retrieving a List of a variable with a ManyToMany relationship using JPA Criteria Query

Tags: java, jpa, many-to-many, hibernate-criteria, criteria-api

In my application, I have a JPA Entity `DocumentSet` which has a ManyToMany relationship with another entity `DocumentType`.
I'm using Criteria Queries, but am struggling to understand how to work with ManyToMany relationships in this context.

The goal is to have the entity return in a DAO:

```
@JsonProperty("id")
private UUID id;

@JsonProperty("name")
private String name;

@JsonProperty("type_descriptions")
private List<String> typeDescriptions;
```

And then build a Criteria Query that uses a join to get access to all the `DocumentType` description variables.

Something along the lines of this incorrect example.

```
Join<DocumentSet, DocumentType> typeJoin = root.join(DocumentSet_.types);

query.multiselect( root.get(...), ......, typeJoin.get(DocumentType_.description));
```

I'm not sure how I should use `ListJoin` or `PluralAttribute` or if this is even possible / a good idea, so any advice is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: The [ListJoin specifications](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/ListJoin.html) have the parameters `ListJoin<Z, E>` where Z - the source type of the join and E - the element type of the target List.
So would this be `ListJoin<DocumentSet, DocumentType>`?

Comment: You've answered your own question. 
Your problem isn't going to be with the query and Join's type, but that you are expecting a List<String> description list somehow - typeJoin.get(DocumentType_.description) will return a single description value - so you will get id/name duplicates with different descriptions because of the join.

Comment: So is there a way that I can have a returned element be a list? Or will I need to do some sort of run through the returned results to filter out duplicates and add the DocumentTypes to a List.

Comment: The later option is the only one I'm aware of. Queries return row data and while JPA can do some magic to turn multiple rows into a single entity, if you aren't using an entity (and want valid pagination at the DB level), you will have to correlate those return values into your single java object instance yourself. Spring view objects I don't believe handle it yet either; doing so would require caching and identity knowledge to tell when one row result is the same but not quite a full duplicate so that the new info can be added to the existing object, and sorting or order isn't a given.